# Sending HTTP Request GET/POST to form with Java?

Tags: java, http, http-post, http-get

So I have this piece of code, and I got it to work, and now it basically allows me to send http post and get requests to almost any external website I want UNLESS the elements don't contain a name attribute. Here's an example:

This is the Java code:

```
    public static String sendPostRequest(String url) {

    StringBuffer sb = null;

    try {

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode("myUserName", "UTF-8") + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("submit", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode("Submit", "UTF-8");


        URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));

        String in = "";
        sb = new StringBuffer();

        while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(in + "\n");
        }

        osw.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is the form I'm trying to send a request to (it's a form on the w3schools site, this being the site http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp):

```
<form name="input0" target="_blank" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">

Username: 

<input type="text" name="user" size="20" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Now because the Submit button doesn't have a name attribute, I can't send a proper HTTP Get/Post request to it (I know it's a get method in this case). What do I replace the String data with (what proper keys/values) so that it actually sends a request to this form?

Answer (score 1):

You don't add the `submit` part to your data at all. This is just for the browser to know that "Submit" button triggers the action. Notice how the URL of the newly opened site looks: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_action.asp?user=myUserName - no `submit` part here. So your `data` code should look like this:

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "="
            + URLEncoder.encode("myUserName", "UTF-8"); // end here
```

Comment: ehm that doesn't work, whether I use it on the html_form_action.asp site or the html_forms.asp site. And I've tried it with other sites, it doesn't work unless I add the submit button part to it...

Comment: This may be because `GET` requests are automatically replaced by `POST` when you call `getOutputStream()`. This is a reasonable thing to do because usually that's what the author meant. To truly issue a `GET` request remove entire `OutputStreamWriter` part and append your `data` to request URL like it should be in a valid GET request: `URL requestUrl = new URL(url + "?" + data);`. Of course you still don't add the `submit` part.

Comment: But that wouldn't be a GET request, that would just be directly getting the HTML source of a certain URL. I need to send a request. I tried to do this by removing the outputstream entirely, but it still just returns the wrong data.

Comment: Well, that's what a GET request indeed is - just a URL with query part (`?someData=value&otherData=value...`). You can just as well type it manually in your browser address bar and press enter. It's the same as if you filled the form and pressed the `submit` button. Think of GET as something like *POST with all data moved from body into URL behind the question mark*. It's a bit oversimplified but will do to catch the idea. Take a look here for full code: http://pastebin.com/Zmf6irXC

Answer (score 0):

I am using HttpClient for generating http request

HttpClient is open source apache project. you can get widely code.
HttpClient version 4.1 is good set of Http api

[HttpClient Learning Artical](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html)

Comment: How is this in any way relative to what I'm trying to do? I'm asking what keys/values I should be using to send an HTTP Post Request to a specific site... not about some kind of API

Comment: @user1007059 : HttpClient will give you better readability you can solve you problem... i am using this httpclien 4.1 in my project and its fetch data from any URL.

Answer (score 0):

//Making http get request

```
HttpClient httpClientDefault1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.your.targer.url.com/page.html");
```

//setup headers (Server understand request throw by some browser)

```
httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", " text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
httpPost.setHeader("Host", "ec2-23-20-44-83.compute-1.amazonaws.com");
```

httpPost.setHeader("Referer",resultUrl+resultUrlAsp);

//Set parameters

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key",""));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtenroll","095020693015"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
```

//Send request

```
HttpResponse httpRespnse = httpClientDefault1.execute(httpPost);
```

//Get Response body

```
if(httpRespnse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
    InputStream in =  httpRespnse.getEntity().getContent();
    byte b[] = new byte[1024] ;
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("");
    while(in.read(b) != -1) {
        html.append((new String(b)).toString());
        b = new byte[1024];
    }
    System.out.println(html);
}
```

also you can get headers, http parameters, cookies, manage the session through the java code... :) :)

Comment: It should be noted that this uses Apache libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ClientHttpRequest class that does all multiparts, files etc, with optional progress tracing and cancelation. It's been around for about 10 years. Pretty simple to use.
Now there's a Scala version too. https://github.com/vpatryshev/ScalaKittens/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalakittens/ClientHttpRequest.scala

http://myjavatools.com/