# Set Request Attributes with ContentExchange

Tags: java, jetty

Is there a way to set request attributes in a `ContentExchange` object? What I have been doing so far is send information to the server in the Request body by using the `setRequestContentSource(InputStream inputstream)` method. But what should I do if I want to send information categorized by field names, say like, `Content`, `Title`, `Author` etc.?

The code that I have as of now is pasted below. Thanks for your help!

```java
exchange.setRequestContentSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(
     serialized.getBytes("UTF-8")));

exchange.setRequestContentType("text/html");
exchange.setMethod("POST");
exchange.setURL(("http://localhost:8089/"));
client.send(exchange);
```

To be more precise, by request attributes, I mean something equivalent to request.setAttribute("Name","ABC"). Only in this case, the request is sent is through the ContentExchange object.

Comment: Be more specific, what do you mean when you say "set request attributes"?

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean something equivalent to request.setAttribute("Name","ABC"). Only in this case, the request is sent is through the ContentExchange object.

I've also added this info in the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so ServletRequest attributes are not part of the HTTP protocol.
There is no standard way to send those attributes via a HTTP protocol.
In fact, the servlet spec itself limits its use for application specific information (such as passing information from a filter to a servlet) and SSL certificate related information.

However, using [standard POST and form data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29#Use_for_submitting_web_forms), via `exchange.setRequestContentType("multipart/form-data");` and obtain those values using [HttpServletRequest.getParameter("Content")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), etc.. similar to how a FORM is submitted from a web browser.  Benefit here, is that you can even provide a simple HTML FORM to test our your application.

Choice #2 is to send your data in a markup like JSON or XML and have the server parse it.
This has the benefit of allowing for hierarchical data.

If this interests you, I'd recommend you read about REST and maybe dig into a REST library like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), [Restlet](http://restlet.org/), and standards like [JAX-RS](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).

Comment: Could you please be a little clearer about how to do it using Standard POST and form data, or point me to a resource/tutorial that shows how? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to format your `serialized` string with `URLEncoder.encode()`, similar to other questions about http form post with java on stackoverflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9954851/775715